# How to declare 2 structs contain each other in c

Tags: c, struct, graph

I am implementing a graph structure for a maze solving program. I declare 2 structs: `vertex` contains `label` to label that vertex, 4 directions of `edge`; `edge` contains `weight` and a `vertex` pointer to 4 other vertices.

```
extern struct graph
{
    int label;
    struct Edge up;
    struct Edge down;
    struct Edge left;
    struct Edge right;
}vertex;

extern struct Edge
{
    int weight;
    struct graph *neighbour;
}edge;

typedef struct graph vertex;
typedef struct Edge edge;
```

This way of declaration leads to some errors: *unknown type name 'vertex'; field 'up' has incomplete type,..*

(I have tried to us `extern` but it doesn't seem to be the problem).

So how do I declare it properly?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You must provide the complete declaration of `struct Edge` before you can include it into a struct. For a pointer it is sufficient to have a forward declaration. Besides that you don't show a `struct graph` at all. Did you mix `graph` and `Vertex`? Also declaring an (external) variable `vertex` and a type `vertex` isn't best idea. Same for `edge`.

Comment: @Gerhardh about `graph`: sorry, this is my typo when I rewrite the typedef, I will edit the post now.

Comment: @Gerhardh can you be more specific on "forward declaration"?

Comment: Detail: "declare 2 structs contain each other" misstates.  One `struct` contains the other. Yet the reverse contains a _pointer_ to the other.  "2 structs contain each other" is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why a `graph` is also a `Vertex`, but you can reverse the order you declare the 2 structs and use a forward declaration. You can also combine the struct declarations and the typedefs.

```
struct graph;  // Forward declaration

typedef struct 
{
    int weight;
    struct graph *neighbour;
} edge;

typedef struct graph 
{
    int label;
    edge up;
    edge down;
    edge left;
    edge right;
} graph;
```

Comment: `graph` and `vertex` is my typo error. so sorry for that. I have added `typedef` before `struct graph;` and it works well. The forward declaration really confuse me at first. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, the code is slightly wrong. Type `graph` is currently undefined at `graph *neighbour;` (except in C++).